# How to change variable value in flutter with bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

Want to ask is **How to change variable value with stream flutter?**

You think my question is so fundamental and I can search in everywhere on internet. But in this scenario with stream, I can't change the variable value with method. How I need to do? please guide me. I will show with example.

Here, this is bloc class code with rxDart.

```
class ChangePinBloc {
  final ChangePinRepository _changePinRepository = ChangePinRepository();
 
 
  final _isValidateConfirmNewPinController = PublishSubject();
  
  String oldPin = '';
  

  Stream get isValidateConfirmNewPinStream =>
      _isValidateConfirmNewPinController.stream;


  void checkValidateConfirmNewPin(
      {required String newPinCode, required String oldPinCode}) {
    if (newPinCode == oldPinCode) {
      oldPin = oldPinCode;
      changePin(newCode: newPinCode);
      isValidateConfirmPin = true;
      
      _isValidateConfirmNewPinController.sink.add(isValidateConfirmPin);
    } else {
      isValidateConfirmPin = false;
      _isValidateConfirmNewPinController.sink.add(isValidateConfirmPin);
    }
  }

 

  void changePin({required String newCode}) async {
    changePinRequestBody['deviceId'] = oldPin;
   
  }

  dispose() {
   
  }
}
```

Above code, want to change the value of `oldPin` value by calling `checkValidateConfirmNewPin` method from UI. And want to use that `oldPin` value in `changePin` method. but `oldPin` value in `changePin` always get empty string.

This is the calling method `checkValidateConfirmNewPin` from UI for better understanding.

```
PinCodeField(
                            pinLength: 6,
                            onComplete: (value) {
                              pinCodeFieldValue = value;
                              changePinBloc.checkValidateConfirmNewPin(
                                  newPinCode: value,
                                  oldPinCode: widget.currentPinCodeFieldValue!);
                            },
                            onChange: () {},
                          ),
```

Why I always get empty String although assign a value to variable?

Lastly, this is complete code that calling state `checkValidateConfirmNewPin` from UI.

```
void main() {
  
  final changePinBloc = ChangePinBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: changePinBloc.isValidateConfirmNewPinStream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot pinValidateSnapshot) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const PinChangeSettingTitle(
                        title: CONFIRM_NEW_PIN_TITLE,
                        subTitle: CONFIRM_NEW_PIN_SUBTITLE,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: margin50,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: margin50, right: margin50),
                        child: PinCodeField(
                          pinLength: 6,
                          onComplete: (value) {
                            changePinBloc.checkValidateConfirmNewPin(
                              newPinCode: value,
                                oldPinCode: widget.newCodePinValue!,
                            );
                          },
                          onChange: () {},
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                pinValidateSnapshot.hasData
                    ? pinValidateDataState(pinValidateSnapshot, changePinBloc)
                    : const Positioned.fill(
                        child: SizedBox(),
                      ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Comment: how many instances of your bloc do you have? for testing add `ChangePinBloc` constructor and do some logging from there and check the logs

Comment: I used only one instance. And then in bloc class, only call ```changePin``` from the  ```checkValidateConfirmNewPin```  method.

Comment: so add some prints inside `checkValidateConfirmNewPin` to be sure that `newPinCode` / `oldPinCode` are not empty, for example: `print('new: |$newPinCode|, old: |$oldPinCode|');`

Comment: Yes.. I check with ```print```. After calling ```checkValidateConfirmNewPin```, the ```oldPinCode``` value is as same as changed value but after calling ```changePin``` the value of ```oldPinCode``` is become empty.

Comment: Sorry, I found. I mess with ```async``` / ```await``` function in my code. ```changePin ``` is ```async``` /  ```await``` function and  it called before assign to ```oldPinCode```.

Answer (score 0):

To update the variable you should emit a new state using emit() method.

Just make sure your bloc is correct as it should inherit from Bloc object. Read [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) documentation to know how to use it.

A simple example:

```
class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {
   ExampleBloc() : super(ExampleInitial()) {
      on<ExampleEvent>((event, emit) {
         //Do some logic here
         emit(ExampleLoaded());
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to write that I used ```Rxdart```, not using ```flutter_bloc```. Your answer may be right but useless for my condition.